# Change the UINavigationBar tint color at runtime with swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I want to change the UINavigationBar tint color at runtime.
I know how to change it only when the application starts with the below code at the App delegate (`didFinishLaunching...`)

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 50.0/255.0, green: 173.0/255.0, blue:240.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3)
```

but can't make it change at runtime. I tried use that code through buttons or segments controls but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the tintColor for `appearance()` is ok for all viewControllers wich will be displayed in the future. For the currently displayed viewController use:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(...)
```

Comment: i want to set for all controllers but make it at runtime,

Comment: Does it work for the currently displayed controller? If yes, what have you tried to get it to work for the other controllers on the navigation stack?

Comment: it doesn't work, i want a way to change it everywhere without the need to close and start the app again.

Comment: i used
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(...) and it work but for the current view, i want to to make it apply to all views, how can i do it?

Comment: @LefterisAltoubas: If that helped please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the hollow checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

- I put at my class in addition of `UITableViewController`.
- I also added the `UIApplicationDelegate`.

So now I want to thank you for the help.